# save_with_captcha is nil in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simplecaptcha

I have home controller and trying to update the field of a table of different controller.

Home controller

```
    class HomeController < ApplicationController

    before_action :user_params, only: [:index]

    def index
      @email = Email.new(user_params)
    end

    def contact
    end

     def faq
     end

    def team
    end

    def privacy
    end

    def esave
    if !user_params.nil?
      if @email.save_with_captcha
        flash[:notice] = "Thank you for registering you email address"
        redirect_to :action => 'index'
      else
        render 'esave'
      end
    end
     end

     def user_params
      params.require(:email).permit(:email, :captcha, :captcha_key) if  params[:email]
   end

 end
```

So I am trying to create new field of Email Model in my home controller but when I click save it throws this error...

```
App 24078 stderr: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
App 24078 stderr: 
App 24078 stderr: NoMethodError (undefined method `save_with_captcha' for nil:NilClass):
App 24078 stderr:   app/controllers/home_controller.rb:37:in `esave'
```

I have email model with defined validations which is like this

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
apply_simple_captcha :message => "The secret Image and code were different", :add_to_base => true
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/ , :message => "Invalid Format"
```

end

So I do not understnd why this save_simple_captcha is nil, any suggestions

Comment: You have to define `@email` Something like `@email = Email.find(params[:id])`

Comment: but I have defined email in Index method already, but then how about user_params validations ?

Comment: You have define it in `esave` method too. Because its an **instance method** and you need to define **instance objects** for every instance method

Comment: you mean email, but I did not define anything in esave

Comment: Yes, so is the error.

Comment: sorry I did not understand, as I am already using user_params which is accessing all the information from email model I guess..

Comment: You need to seriously learn the basics

Comment: Yes I understand, but I do not work at all in rails, somebody asked me to add small feature, and I do not intend to continue working with rails, so I did in this as soon as I can ..

Answer (score 0):

Here my 2 cents.

Remember HTTP is stateless. You have defined `@email` in the index, you have gotten to the `esave` after page has been refreshed so `@email` is no longer available. 
( Controller is a bit different that straight Ruby Class that get instantiated and variables can be tossed around )

You HAVE TO instantiate the `@email` for the method your are in.
I don't know what is in your Model so I can just guess the rest.

This `@email = Email.find(params[:id])` might or might not work as I don't know your model. ( as mentioned in other comments )

***Put your model here too. We might be able to help you out.***

PS: It is not a good idea to accept to code on a framework when you don't know a very basic of it :)